# Concat function is not working - invalid number of arguments

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with two columns(Name, Occupation). I want to output the value in a format something like this.

```
Jane(A) 
Jenny(D) 
Julia(A)
```

Hear First one is the name and the value in brackets is the first letter of their occupation.

So far what I have done is

```
SELECT CONCAT(Name,SUBSTR(Occupation,1,1)) FROM OCCUPATIONS;
```

which output value like this

```
JaneS 
JennyS 
JuliaD
```

to get the required format I tried this

```
SELECT CONCAT(Name,"(",SUBSTR(Occupation,1,1),")") FROM OCCUPATIONS;
```

then it's throwing an error something like this.

> SELECT CONCAT(Name,'(',SUBSTR(Occupation,1,1),')') FROM OCCUPATIONS 
>   *  ERROR at line 1:  ORA-00909: invalid number of arguments

What is the mistake that I have done and what should I do to fix it.

Comment: Error code looks like from Oracle not mysql

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> ```
> SELECT CONCAT(Name,"(",SUBSTR(Occupation,1,1),")") FROM OCCUPATIONS;
> ```

First, the double quotes `"` are used to enclose identifiers. use single quote `'` to wrap a string.

Second, `CONCAT` accepts two params.

You could nest bunch of concats, but it's easier and cleaner to use concatenation operation `||`:

```
SELECT Name || '('  || SUBSTR(Occupation,1,1) || ')' FROM OCCUPATIONS;
```

Comment: concat can accept more than two arguments. the issue is with the double quotes only.

Comment: @NirLevy - [Really? You should try it here](http://rextester.com/DZO32299). You must be talking about MySQL.

Comment: @NirLevy: the  [Oracle Database SQL Language Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/database/122/SQLRF/CONCAT.htm#SQLRF00619) says: `CONCAT(char1, char2)`

Answer (score 3):

You can use just || for concatenating

```
select c1  ||   c2 ||   c3 || c4   as  col from mytable
```

Answer (score 3):

you may try this

```
select CONCAT(CONCAT(FIRST_NAME,' '),LAST_NAME) from employees;
```

By using this you have to give number of nested CONCAT functions equals to the number of arguments

*Results*

```
CONCAT(CONCAT(FIRST_NAME,''),LAST_NAME)
```

- Neena kochhar
- steven king
- Alexander Hunold

Answer (score 1):

This happens to be one reason why I prefer `replace()` over `concat()`:

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE('{Name} ({Occ})', '{Name}', Name'
                      ), '{Occ}', SUBSTR(Occupation, 1, 1)
              )
```

You can readily see the format of the string being created and easily change it.  Also, `REPLACE()` converts arguments to the appropriate type (which Oracle does with string concatenation anyway).